# jQuery not working when page is called via ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

This is the `index.html` page

```
<head>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
    <script src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
    <script src="js/animated-menu.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
    <script src="js/call.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/fade.js"></script>
</head>  

<body>
    <div class="header">         
        <div class="menu">
            <ul>  
                <li class="green" >  
                    <p><a href="index.html">Home</a></p>  
                    <p class="subtext">The front page</p>  
                </li>  
                <li class="yellow" onclick="showHint(1)">  
                    <p><a href="#">About</a></p>  
                    <p class="subtext">More info</p>  
                </li>  
                <li class="red" onclick="showHint(2)">  
                    <p><a href="#">Contact</a></p>  
                    <p class="subtext">Get in touch</p>  
                </li>  
                <li class="blue">  
                    <p><a href="#">Submit</a></p>  
                    <p class="subtext">Send us your stuff!</p>  
                </li>  
                <li class="purple">  
                    <p><a href="#">Terms</a></p>  
                    <p class="subtext">Legal things</p>  
                </li>  
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div> 
    <div class="content" id="content"></div>
</body>
```

This is the `contact.html` which I'm loading via AJAX

```
<head>
    <script src="js/call.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <p>Rollover a menu item to expand it.</p>  
<h1>Hello Ajax</h1>    
</body>
```

Here is the `fade.js` file

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("body").css("display", "none");
    $("body").fadeIn(2000);
});
```

And finally here is the ajax call

```
var XMLHttpRequestObject;
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        XMLHttpRequestObject=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else if(window.ActiveXObject)
    {
        XMLHttpRequestObject=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    function showHint(ide) {
        if(XMLHttpRequestObject)
        {
            XMLHttpRequestObject.onreadystatechange=function() {
                if(XMLHttpRequestObject.readyState == 4 && XMLHttpRequestObject.status == 200)
                {
                    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML=XMLHttpRequestObject.responseText;
                }
            }
            if(ide=="0")
            {
                XMLHttpRequestObject.open("GET","index.html",true);
            }
            else if(ide=="1")
            {
                XMLHttpRequestObject.open("GET","about_me.htm",true);
            }
            else if(ide=="2")
            {
                XMLHttpRequestObject.open("GET","contact.htm",true);
            }
        XMLHttpRequestObject.send();
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I'm calling the contact page separately, the fade effect is working. But when I'm loading the `contact.html` via AJAX, the jQuery effect is not working. Please help.

Comment: I don't see anything that resembles jQuery method calls.

Comment: sorry , post updated now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to include in `contact.html`, all necessary libraries as given below:

```
<head>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
    <script src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
    <script src="js/animated-menu.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
    <script src="js/call.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/fade.js"></script>
</head>
```

EDIT:

First you should learn how to use jQuery's ajax: http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/, also include the latest version of the library if you can.

Second I think you want the fade in effect on body after every ajax call. In that case in contact.htm you only need to have the content from the body. Everything put together bellow:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
     <script src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
     <script src="js/animated-menu.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var XMLHttpRequestObject;
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        XMLHttpRequestObject=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else if(window.ActiveXObject)
    {
        XMLHttpRequestObject=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    function showHint(ide) {
        if(XMLHttpRequestObject)
        {
            XMLHttpRequestObject.onreadystatechange=function() {
                if(XMLHttpRequestObject.readyState == 4 && XMLHttpRequestObject.status == 200)
                {
                    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML=XMLHttpRequestObject.responseText;

                    $("body").css("display", "none");
                    $("body").fadeIn(2000);
                }
            }
            if(ide=="0")
            {
                XMLHttpRequestObject.open("GET","index.html",true);
            }
            else if(ide=="1")
            {
                XMLHttpRequestObject.open("GET","about_me.htm",true);
            }
            else if(ide=="2")
            {
                XMLHttpRequestObject.open("GET","contact.htm",true);
            }
        XMLHttpRequestObject.send();
    }
}
    </script>    
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
$("body").css("display", "none");
    $("body").fadeIn(2000);
});
    </script>
</head>  

<body>
    <div class="header">         
        <div class="menu">
            <ul>  
                <li class="green" >  
                    <p><a href="index.html">Home</a></p>  
                    <p class="subtext">The front page</p>  
                </li>  
                <li class="yellow" onclick="showHint(1)">  
                    <p><a href="#">About</a></p>  
                    <p class="subtext">More info</p>  
                </li>  
                <li class="red" onclick="showHint(2)">  
                    <p><a href="#">Contact</a></p>  
                    <p class="subtext">Get in touch</p>  
                </li>  
                <li class="blue">  
                    <p><a href="#">Submit</a></p>  
                    <p class="subtext">Send us your stuff!</p>  
                </li>  
                <li class="purple">  
                    <p><a href="#">Terms</a></p>  
                    <p class="subtext">Legal things</p>  
                </li>  
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div> 
    <div class="content" id="content"></div>
</body> 
</html>
```

Your contact.html:

```
<p>Rollover a menu item to expand it.</p>
```

Comment: did that , but too not working.!! actually the scripts are not getting called when the page is loaded via ajax. any solution for this ?

Comment: Edited the answer. See if that works for you now. The most important part is that you call the fadein function for the body after `document.getElementById("content").innerHTML=XMLHttpRequestObject.responseText;`

Comment: Thx a lot man , this is working . But what if i want a external jquery script to be executed after every ajax call ? pls help :)

Comment: You place that script in the head of the index.html and any function you want to add in the same place you placed fadein function, inside if(XMLHttpRequestObject.readyState == 4 && XMLHttpRequestObject.status == 200) { }